# Does mysqli_connect close automatically at the end of script?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm wondering, if `mysqli_connect()` does automatically close at the end of the script. I know, that `mysql_connect()` does, but I'm speaking about improved `mysqli_connect()`.. Also I found answered question, that says it does, but in official documentation it is not written.. So, can I rely on those not official statements? (Or better to ask, it is safe to rely on them?)

Comment: The unofficial statements are correct - it'll close automatically on the termination of the script.

If you don't trust the unofficial statements (this included), just put together a simple test - fire up a virtual machine with MySQL and a `max_connections` setting of something like 5, and try refreshing a test PHP script 10-15 times. It'll still work.

Comment: You'll see some ['unofficial official'](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) stuff here. It does close.

Comment: ok, thanks guys, this is what i wanted to hear ;) Other statements had not any reason for it, your reason with max_connection is great..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you should consider. The MySql connection does automatically close when the script terminates. However, if your script does a lot of processing after the data has been retrieved and stored to an array or whatever you store it to, it is safer to close the connection explicitly so you do not face the chance of running out of available connections while the script is busy running the post data retrieval routines. For me, I just explicitly close the connection. It's a habit I've developed and my fingers auto-type the command.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was just wondering what will happend, after die()/exit() functions with connection, becouse I use it after mysqli_query() function for handling errors. And in that point, the script is left without explicit mysqli_close()

Comment: Since die() causes an immediate termination of the script, you have nothing to worry about. The connection is closed.